# Archiving multiple files in Unix using tar and gzip

Tags: unix, gzip, tar

I have the requirement to archive multiple files keeping the original files using **tar** and **gzip**. I cannot take risks with the files I have.

For example, the files to be archived are:

```
ls
1.doc
2.doc
3.doc
4.xls
5.xls
6.xls
```

The expected output:

```
ls
1.doc
2.doc
3.doc
4.xls
5.xls
6.xls
archive.tar.gz
```

Where `archive.tar.gz` file contains all the doc and xls files.

Comment: What is your question?  If the question is just "how do I do this", the answer you're going to get is "read the documentation for `tar` and `gzip`".

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestion. Will try next time if I get a free to do anything session.

Comment: If you want to produce a smaller archive by using similarities between the archived files, see [this question](https://powerusers.codidact.com/posts/286389) and answer on Codidact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try the command:

```
tar czf archive.tar.gz *.doc *.xls
```

Options here are:

- c: Create
- z: Gzip
- f: Output file

To extract:

```
tar xzf archive.tar.gz
```

You can read [the manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tar.1.html) of the tar command for advanced options:

```
man tar
```